# Linq query in not returning value when taking input from TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, oracle10g, entity-framework-4.1

Here is the image of the model. You can see the column i am searching is type string.

[image]

Now I just want to take input from a text box and match it with the desired column.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String val = Convert.ToString(TextBox1.Text.Trim());
    Entities query = new Entities();

    var txn = (from p in query.MAINs
               where p.PAN.Equals(val, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
              select p).ToList();
    GridView1.DataSource = txn.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

but the query returns null(rowcount=0). I have checked the val variable. its sending the exact parameter. when I am giving the value direct then its returning result.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String val = Convert.ToString(TextBox1.Text.Trim());
    Entities query = new Entities();

    var txn = (from p in query.MAINs
               where p.PAN.Equals("1010170000000030", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
              select p).ToList();
    GridView1.DataSource = txn.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I am newbie to Linq and entity framework. This thing driving me nuts. Have no idea why taking input from a text box is not working. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated as I am stuck in this for 3 days. Please help me out.

Comment: why are you trimming the textbox1.Text ? Also, do you really need the StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase in your where statement?

Comment: yes i trim textbox1.text. no i dont need StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase in the where clause.

Comment: can you delete the ordinalIgnorecase and see if it works?

Comment: Yes i have done that. but results come same. Here i want to tell you that if i use p.pan.contains() or startswith() than its returning result. But for the client requirement i need the equals to work. Thanks.

Comment: this is a longshot, but try using where p.PAN == "1010170000000030" instead of .Equals()

Comment: man i have tried that too .......... that returns data we are giving inputs directly instead of from text box. but if i put p.pan == val than its not returning.

Comment: can it be a matter of page encoding by any chance ?

Comment: page encoding ? i dont get the issue.will u explain a bit?

Comment: Can you do some sort of trace on the database itself when the query is executed?  This will show you the SQL that is being generated and might expose why one version works and the other doesn't.

Comment: as your hardcoded value is working but value from webpage is not ,maybe encoding format is different for code (or database) and webpage .

Comment: TLS as i am using oracle database tracing the database giving me the following error ORA-02002: error while writing to audit trail
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kzaSqlBindLob1], [22923], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-22923: amount of data specified in streaming LOB write is 0. so unable to trace it and also need to stop the database audit.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var txn = (from p in query.MAINs
           where p.PAN.Trim().Equals("1010170000000030", 
               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
          select p).ToList();
```

I get the feeling that the field PAN in the Oracle table is `char`/`nchar` and not `varchar`.